# Angular 2+ w/Jasmine Testing: [ngClass]=”methodName(configObj)” issue

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I’ve read through the entire angular.io testing document, googled for keywords and used the advanced search here at S.O. but didn’t find anything applicable to my case.  I’m new to unit testing so maybe I just don’t have the terminology yet.  If this is duplicate just point me in the right direction please.

Foreshadowing:  My question is

A.) Is angular/jasmine capable of testing dynamic parameters from template method calls.

or else...

B.) How would you mock passing parameters into a method during every fixture.detectChanges()?

Here’s the situation and the failing code...

```
<generic-element 
  *ngFor=”let recordObj of recordsArray” 
  [ngClass]=”doSetClasses(recordObj)”
></generic-element>
```

In summary, I’ve got a component template in which an element dynamically gets it’s classes assigned via a method. This method takes an object (extracted from a list via ngFor directive) and examines it to determine the class names it should return to the template.  I prefer assignment via method for really verbose assignments because I try to keep my logic in the typescript file and the structure in the HTML….as much as possible at least.

My very simple unit tests are failing because “Cannot read property 'id' of undefined” (undefined in this case is the recordObj being passed into doSetClasses() method from template.  I’ve isolated it to this because if I simply overwrite and strip out the contents of doSetClasses method in the test environment everything passes, such as:

```
beforeEach {
   ...
   component.doSetClasses = function() { return; } as any;
}
```

Now if I keep doSetClasses method as is, I’ve noticed that if I don’t call fixture.detectChanges() it also passes.  So my problem seems to be: testing methods, that are called from the template, which also have parameters included from the template, during angular’s change detection/digest cycle.

My question is

A.) Is angular/jasmine capable of testing dynamic parameters from template method calls.

or else...

B.) How would you mock passing a parameter into a method during every fixture.detectChanges() in the test environment?

Again, if this is duplicate just point me in the right direction please.

Thanks in advance for any help, suggestions, guidance.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of no answers, comments or questions it looks like there will be no guidance submitted.  So for anyone who may find this in the future with a similar issue here is what I arrived at:

1. I don't believe there is a way to organically have [ngClass]="doSetClasses(recordObj)", which is called every digest cycle, dynamically getting it's params from *ngFor, work in a unit test, so therefore I had to mock it.
2. In the test environment create a copy of doSetClasses() method.
3. Then strip out the contents of the original doSetClasses() method so it can still be called by the code/other tests, but ends up doing absolutely nothing.
4. When testing the actual use of doSetClasses itself, use the copy instead and mock the scenario.

I do not have access to my code at the moment but here is the shorthand:

```
beforeEach() {
  //Create a copy to use in controlled scenarios
  const doSetClassesCopy = doSetClasses;
  //Then strip out contents so it can be called but does not error during testing
  doSetClasses = function() { return; } as any;
}

...
(The Test)
  //Now mock it's performance with params from template's *ngFor directive
  const simulatedParamsFromTemplate = { value: 'whatever' } as recordObj;
  const outcome = doSetClassesCopy(simulatedParamsFromTemplate);
  expect(outcome).toBe('Whatever I expect.');
```

If anyone has a better solution or suggestion I'd be interested in hearing it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue today. Calling `fixture.detectChanges()` seem to trigger the calling of the function mentioned in `ngClass`.

I want to call `validateField` which will assign `Bootstrap`'s class to a control

HTML

```
<form class="form-inline" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="signInUser()" novalidate>
            <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username" formControlName="userName" [ngClass]="validateField('userName')" required>
            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" formControlName="password" [ngClass]="validateField('password')" required>
...
```

The `validateField` function in `.ts` is

```
/*

  This function will eventually return object of type depending on whether the field is valid or not, set Bootstrap's css
   {
      'is-invalid': true or false, // if fieldvalid returns false i.e. field is not valid then we want has-error css. So set it to true (opp. of fieldValid)
      'is-valid': true or false //if fieldvalid returns true i.e. field is valid then we want has-success css. So set it to true (value of fieldValid)
   }
   */
  validateField(field:string){
   // console.log("validating field: " +field)
    return this.helper.validateField(this.loginForm,field);
  }
```

My `spec` is

```
fit('it should validate that the data in username and password field has correct format',()=>{
    let navComponent = component;
    let helperService = TestBed.get(HelperService);
    spyOn(helperService,'validateField');
    let formControls = navComponent.loginForm.controls;
    let email = 'test@test.com';
    let password = 'testpassword';
    formControls['userName'].setValue(email);
    fixture.detectChanges(); //<-- THIS SEEM TO TRIGGER THE CALLING OF VALIDATION FUNCTION
    expect(helperService.validateField).toHaveBeenCalledWith(navComponent.loginForm,'userName');
    formControls['password'].setValue(password);
    fixture.detectChanges();//<-- THIS SEEM TO TRIGGER THE CALLING OF VALIDATION FUNCTION
    expect(helperService.validateField).toHaveBeenCalledWith(navComponent.loginForm,'password');

  });
```